# How to rotate the image while keeping its actual dimensions?

Tags: python, image, rotation, image-rotation

I am trying to solve a problem with image rotation. I have some PNG image that contains a photo of a solar panel. It is cropped exactly around the panel. I place this image in a satellite map, where it represents its exact real size(say 1x2 meters) in relation to scale. I need to create a Python function that will rotate the original image by a specified angle and create a rotated image with a transparent background around the panel. But the problem is with the size... I need the function to also resize the image so that when I reinsert it into the map, the panel will again represent its real size(1x2m). How to do this? Thank you in advance for any valuable advice or code examples.

[Here is the original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5lCw.png)

[Here is example of rotated image(but with bad size)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCqgn.png)

EDIT: [Here you can see what the problem looks like on the map. The original panel is noticeably larger than the rotated one.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaTPy.png)

I tried to use such a function, but it has a problem with the size after inserting it into the map. The panel size is smaller.

```py
def rotate_img(angle):
    image_path = '/static/images/panel.png'
    rotated_image_path = '/static/images/panel_rotated.png'

    original_image = Image.open(image_path).convert("RGBA")

    rotation_angle = float(angle)
    rotated_image = original_image.rotate(rotation_angle, expand=True, 
    resample=Image.BICUBIC)

    rotated_image.save(rotated_image_path)
```

Comment: Are you asking how to scale down the rotated image to represent the pixel dimensions of the original image?